# Why does this Regex not match properly?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I basically have this:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\$(?:(\$)|(\{(?<ex>.*?)\}))");
string s = "${P#(n*8+1)!=0$$P}${P#(n*8+1)!=0$N/A$[n*8+1]}";

Match m = rx.Match(s, 0);
```

The first match is `"${P#(n*8+1)!=0$N/A$[n*8+1]}"` when it should be `"${P#(n*8+1)!=0$$P}"`. If I put an extra space before the first `'$'`, it works fine.

Comment: It *is* a strange regex, but it does match both strings. (It matches the first string starting from the `$`)

Comment: @TimPietzcker For me, `Regex.IsMatch(@"\$(?:(\$)|(\{(?<ex>.*?)\}))", "${foo}")` returns false.

Comment: @TimPietzcker nevermind that's not what I meant. But there is still a bug in my code relating to this.

Comment: That's because you've got the parameters in the wrong order.

Comment: With the parameters the right way around, +1 to "both match" from me.

Comment: I still get your "expected" answer with your code literally copy/pasted.

Comment: @Rawling UPDATE: in my code, I also give a starting index of `0`

Comment: Nevermind guys, of course after I ask this question, my code starts working.

Comment: \o/ The magic of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

You are swapping the arguments. `Regex.IsMatch` signature is:

```
public static bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern)
```

EDIT: the following code prints `True` twice for me.

```
var p = @"\$(?:(\$)|(\{(?<ex>.*?)\}))";
var regex = new Regex(p);
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(" ${foo}"));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("${foo}"));
```

EDIT2: deleted the previous edit, the match works for me.

Comment: I'm not actually swapping the arguments, in my code I have a Regex object whose `.Match` method I use.